# View photos in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-photos-and-videos

Google Maps used to have a strip of photos at the bottom, which came either from Google Streetview, migrated from Panoramio, or from different sources.  I can't seem to find this anymore.  Does this feature still exist?  How do I enable it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a bar in the bottom right with three small thumbnails and a double up arrow.  This does not show if Google Maps is showing routing, even if the side panel is collapsed.

To make this show, uncollapse the side panel and make sure there is no routing shown; click the X to undo any routing.  After this, the thumbnails to go to photo viewing should show up, either with he side panel shown or collapsed.

Comment: This control disappears if you have *any* place selected, even if you haven't asked for directions to it.