# Is there a way to view the User contributed images on google maps as thumbnails like in google image search?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-photos-and-videos

So, I want to see how the entrance to a national park looks, there are no relevant images in google image search. There are 100s of Google map - user contributed images for the location. I feel there is a chance someone has posted an image I'm looking for.

The problem is, I am [scrolling](https://i.ibb.co/Y7mzqQF/Scrolling-To-Find-Pic.gif) endlessly trying to find the one. If there is a way to get all these images show up like [thumbnails](https://i.ibb.co/Xb1czjm/national-park-search.jpg) on google image search, I can quickly recognize the one I need and that would save me a lot of time!

Is there anyway to do this? Please do suggest if there is something else that you think might help me do this faster. Thank you!

Comment: Related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/107009/88163